# Error Trying To Fill Data Table

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, sqlconnection, sqldataadapter

This is my syntax, but I get an error of

> The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.

what do I need to do in order to be able to fill the data table?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=Test;Database=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
{
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[selfservice] WHERE saleID = @userid;";
command.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@userid"].Value = row.Field<string>("saleID");
command.Connection = conn;                    
using (SqlDataAdapter dataadapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter()
{
    dataadapter1.Fill(dtData);
}
}
```

Comment: mark as answer if it has helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you're not using the command object. You need to add the select command to your adapter:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter dataadapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter()
{
    dataadapter1.SelectCommand = command
    dataadapter1.Fill(dtData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify select command of SqlDataAdapter before Fill, also you are missing a close parenthesis at the end

```
using (SqlDataAdapter dataadapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    dataadapter1.SelectCommand=command; 
    dataadapter1.Fill(dtData);
}
```